# SQL JOIN query with IN Laravel's way

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I hope this is a good question to post here.

I want to transform this raw MySQL query into Laravel style using the methods Laravel offers us.

```
    $query = 'SELECT musicos.id, musicos.nombre, roles.titulo FROM musicos
    INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id IN
        (SELECT rol_id FROM detalles_cancion WHERE cancion_id=1 AND musico_id=musicos.id);

    return \DB::select(\DB::raw($query));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want eloquent way or db build query way....??

Comment: i suggest using db build query , more easy than eloquent,...as per as my prefence

Comment: @iamawesome db build query please